# SQL Update (Не работает)

Tags: sql, c++builder, firebird

Сервак `FireBird 2.0`
СУБД  `IBExpert`
Среда разработки `Embarcadero Rad Studio 2010 (C++)`

Имеется таблица товаров, удаление, селект, добавление пашут, а вот апдейт не канает ни в какую.

Таблица товаров имеет три поля - ID, Лейбл, Цена.
Средства разработки `BDE`
Ставлю в датамодуле все соответствующие компоненты - `IBDatabase` в котором путь к базе, `IBTransaction`, `TIBQuerry` - в котором селект из таблицы, `TDataSource` и `TIBStoredProc` - который выполняет процедуру (НА каждую по одному).

Вот, данные выводятся в `DBGrid`, в дбгриде выбираю строку, нажимаю на баттн который вызывает форму изменения записи, там два поля эдит заполняются данными из изменяемой строки.... Далее я меняю их значения, нажимаю на `ОК` что выполняет следующую процедуру

```
DMD->goods_U->ParamByName("label")->Value=Edit1->Text;
DMD->goods_U->ParamByName("costforsingle")->Value=StrToFloat(Edit2->Text);
```

Где
`DMD` - модуль данных где находятся компоненты BDE,
`goods_U` - компонент `TIBStoredProc` реализующий апдейт,
`LABEL` и `costforsingle` соответственно поля таблицы.

Текст `SQL` на апдейт:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE GOODS
  SET
      LABEL = :LABEL,
      COSTFORSINGLE = :COSTFORSINGLE
  WHERE (label = :label);
END
```

Апдейт не работает... Никак.

Может, хотя не может, а что-то не правильно? Подскажите плиз)

Comment: Если поменялся label, то update не произойдет или хуже - проапдейтится что-то другое. Вы ищите существующую запись по новому значению, а не по старому.  

ЗЫ Зачем вам хранимая, когда можно обойтись IBUpdateSQL? или это пример просто?...

Comment: Ммм, не, не пример, а что за UpdateSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а комит кто делать будет Иван Федорович Крузенштерн?

добавьте **COMMIT** у транзакции.

Comment: С++ не моя родная среда, но скорее всего типа так **IBTransaction->Commit;**

Comment: Спасибо) Совсем из головы вылетело)

Answer (score 0):

> SET
>       LABEL = :LABEL,
> WHERE (label = :label);

Если регистр не имеет значения, то вы меняете значение на ЕГО ЖЕ.

Comment: Ну судя по тексту запроса там обновляется не только **label** но и **COSTFORSINGLE**.

Если быть точнее то обновляется **COSTFORSINGLE** а **label** остается такой же

Comment: Ну, поскольку Label менять вообще не нужно, то могу предположить, что и с COSTFORSINGLE нечисто. :-) Оно, кажется, из той же строки берется.

Comment: нет **COSTFORSINGLE** передается в запрос другим параметром.
ИМХО он не завершает транзакцию комитом вот по этому и изменений не видит, FireBird имеет версионую архитектуру

Comment: Чтения бывают "грязные", но я не знаю специфики FireBird, потому буду соглашаться со всем сказанным. Однако хотелось бы услышать что-нибудь от автора вопроса. Ему вроде как это больше нужно. :-)